# Get XSLT result as text and use in another XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to use one XSLT result as text value for an element in another XSLT.

Example: My output XML should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a>xxx</a>
  <b>yyy</b>
  <c>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><order><header>....</order>
  </c>
</root>
```

"Order.xsl" is used to get  XML.

"Main.xsl" is used to get  XML which has to call "Order.xsl" and get the result as text for  element.

Please can you give your suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your output "XML" is not actually well-formed XML so you can't produce it using XSLT. It wouldn't be very useful if you could, because no XML parser would accept it. An XML declaration is permitted only at the start of the XML document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. I understand that we should have XML declaration only at the start point. But the output XML is being used by an third party application and their requirement is to have full XML embed as text inside <c> element. The whole content inside <c> element should be text or string.  Please let me know if there is any option. Thanks!

Comment: The output is not XML, so please don't refer to it as XML. It's perfectly legal to use non-XML formats, but please don't expect XML tools to support them.

Comment: Having said that, when your output format is close to being XML but not quite, you can often generate it using disable-output-escaping. But first please try to encourage your third-party partner that it would be more convenient for everyone if they switched to using well-formed XML.